# Problems running hello-neon example in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am needing to check if the device has NEON capabilities. I was able to copy the contents of the hello-neon sample project into my project to make this check and it worked great, but I was using Eclipse and Linux. Now I have switched to Android Studio and Windows and getting build errors.

I am getting this error:

```
C:/Users/mark/android-ndk32-r10-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include/arm_neon.h:32:2: error: #error You must enable NEON instructions (e.g. -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon) to use arm_neon.h
```

I tried adding LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon to Android.mk, but got the same error. I am not really sure what I need to do since it worked fine before.

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated! I would post more info, but I am not sure what all info would be relevant in this situation.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I download the newest NDK, android-ndk-r10e. Now I am getting an error saying that it can't find cpu-features.h.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If yes please post answer. I am also stuck in same issue have look on my question...... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277243/how-to-build-and-debug-native-code-c-with-neon-enabled-in-android-studio